# Displaying Modal pop up on top frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

I have a requirement to show a modal pop up in a jsp on link click. The problem is that the jsp has been divided into frames. The link is present in one of the frames and ofcourse the pop up needs to be on top of the screen masking every frame. But it shows the pop up masking only the current frame and not the entire screen.
This is what I have in terms of code. I got this from a blog but need help with some modifications :

**CSS:**

```
#mask {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  z-index:9000;
  background-color:#000;
  display:none;
}

#boxes .window {
  position:fixed;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width:900px;
  height:600px;
  display:none;
  z-index:9999;
  padding:20px;
}

#boxes #dialog {
  width:375px; 
  height:203px;
  padding:10px;
  background-color:#ffffff;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('a[name=modal]').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr('href');
        var maskHeight = $(document).height();
        var maskWidth = $(window).width();
        $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

        $('#mask').fadeIn(1000);    
        $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.8);  

        var winH = $(window).height();
        var winW = $(window).width();
        $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
        $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);
        $(id).fadeIn(2000); 
    });

    $('.window .close').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#mask').hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });     

    $('#mask').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });         
});
```

And the HTML CODE is :

```
<a href="#dialog" name="modal" target="_top" style="text-decoration: none;">CLICK</a>

    <div id="boxes">
        <div id="dialog" class="window">
        Modal Window 
        </div>

        <div id="mask"></div>
    </div>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - Move your modal block code (HTML) to the top frame;

2 - Include all required libraries to open a modal in the top frame as well (jQuery and any other).

You can call the function in top frame instead using [top property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_top.asp) from window. It will return the window reference on top frame (where all functions are placed). You have to deal with something like this:

TOP FRAME CODE:

```
  function openModal(id) {
    var winH = $(window).height();
    var winW = $(window).width();
    $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
    $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);
    $(id).fadeIn(2000); 
  }
```

CURRENT FRAME CODE CALL:

```
  top.openModal(id);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am not sure I follow very well. May be for the lack of my Javascript knowledge. It makes sense to put the code in the top frame so the window reference is for the parent. But how will I access the method since I would need to call it from the child frame now.

Comment: when you call "top" from a child frame. It will return a refference to the highest frame Window. That's why you have to call top.openModal(id). When you do it from a child it will cal a function placed in the parent frame

Comment: just by using top (or parent) you can call any function from parent frames

Comment: Sorry I cant access the method. I have tried top.openModal(id);, parent.openModal(id);, window.top.openModal(id);, window.parent.openModal(id);

Answer (score 1):

Spend 1 day to open modal windows from iframe document 
first i did single case :

```
parent.$("#you_modal_window_selector").css("visibility", "visible");
```

!!! keyword changin matter is PARENT. (in small letters)

Second i change all buttons in a document with script:

```
<script> 
 $(function() {
        $(".open-modal").on("click", function (e) {
            var $this = $(this),
            $href = $this.attr("href");
            e.preventDefault();
            parent.$($href).css("visibility", "visible");
            parent.$(".modal-window-dark").css("visibility", "visible");
        });
    });
</script>
```